# Newtonian contribution to perihelion precession of Mercury

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, perturbation-theory, planets, precession

> We have seen that the orbits of the planets around the sun can be
> found, to a good approximation, by only considering a two-body system
> (a planet and the sun) interacting through a central force. However,
> all the other planets cause slight variations in the predicted path of
> an individual planet. Astronomers have been able to calculate the
> expected precession of Mercury’s apsides (due to the forces of other
> planets) to be 531 arcseconds per century, and they have observed that
> the actual precession is 574 arcseconds per century. This leaves a
> difference of 43" that could not be explained by uncertainties in
> calculation or measurement and which was noticed as early as 1845.

Source: [https://www.tau.ac.il/~morris/03411203/chapter3/mercury_paper.pdf](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Emorris/03411203/chapter3/mercury_paper.pdf)

As we can see from the quote above that the precession of mercury had been calculated to an amazing degree of accuracy well before Einstein's theory of general relativity. To account for the difference between the calculated value and the one predicted by Newton's theory, they came up with mistaken ideas of Vulcan and dust clouds. It was Einstein's theory which gave a final answer. The orbits of all other planets also precess but the value is too small and astronomers in the past didn't notice it for other planets other than Mercury.

Perihelion is the closest point to the sun while the aphelion is the farthest for any orbit.

My question is about the Newtonian precession of 531 arcseconds per century. Suppose, we are looking at the picture shown below from above the solar system. It could be assumed that all the planets lie in same plane. Looking from the top, one would say that precession is taking place counterclockwise as if some force is gradually pulling the entire orbit of planet Mercury in counterclockwise direction.

[image]

Source: https://www.astronomicalreturns.com/2020/05/the-mystery-of-mercurys-missing.html

The Newtonian precession of 531 arcseconds per century was the result of gravitational attraction of other planets onto Mercury. The picture below shows the relative sizes of the planets and their distance from the sun. I think that Mercury should be affected most by Venus, Earth, Mars, and Jupiter since these planets are relatively close to Mercury's orbit. Mercury takes almost 88 days to orbit the sun.

[image]

Source: https://www.wikihow.com/Draw-the-Solar-System

As I said earlier, it appears as if Mercury's orbit is being pulled in counterclockwise direction which suggests, at least to me, that mostly other planets were in such a configuration that their resultant pull onto Mercury was in the counterclockwise direction. If it was not true then there would be times when Mercury's orbit could precess or slide in clockwise direction as well. The diagram below is a crude attempt to show you how I'm thinking. The orbit in cyan is for Mercury, the orbit in red is for Venus, and so on. The arrows show the pull of shown planets onto Mercury.

Could you please let me know if I'm thinking along the right lines? I'm trying to understand it intuitively.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are essentially correct to assume that the precession is sometimes backwards as well. The frequently quoted value of 531"/cy is only the long term net average. In reality there is a considerable oscillatory component added to this, as illustrated in the following schematic figure

[image: precession of perihelion]

The oscillation period here is essentially the orbital period of the disturbing planet. The effect is exaggerated here just to demonstrate it. If you do the same calculation with the actual data for all planets, you get the following graph for Mercury's Newtonian perihelion precession

[image: Mercury Perihelion precession]

Although the increase of the perihelion angle is now closer to a linear increase, there is still a considerable wobble, and at times it is going backwards for a few years. The two main periods in the oscillation visible here are those of Jupiter and Venus, which have the largest impact on the precession (Jupiter due to its mass and Venus due to its proximity)

For more details see the web page [Mercury's Perihelion Advance](http://www.alternativephysics.org/book/MercuryPerihelion.htm) from which also the above figures were taken

---

EDIT: Let me add a qualitative explanation of what is happening here:

an outer planet in opposition to Mercury (i.e. on the same side of the Sun) will result in a small force pulling it away from the Sun. So if Mercury is moving away from the Sun again after its closest approach (perihelion) the gravitational force of the Sun will effectively be *reduced* slightly and it takes longer to bring the radial velocity back to zero again. This means Mercury will go slightly further in its orbit until it has reached its furthest point (aphelion) i.e. a positive precession. If however the disturbing planet is on the opposite side of the Sun, its gravitational field will effectively *increase* the gravitational field of the Sun, so the effect will be the other way around, leading to a negative (backwards) precession. In the latter case the planet is further away though than in opposition, so the effect is smaller, leaving an overall positive (forward) precession on average. The net result can therefore be seen as an oscillatory precession angle (related to the time dependent orbital motion of the disturbing planet) superposed on a linearly increasing precession angle related to the time averaged mass distribution of the planet (which is effectively a circle/ellipse and thus always produces an outward directed force i.e. a positive precession)

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just curious, I remember that yesterday I saw another answer to my question mentioning something about  gravitational potential. I checked it on my phone and couldn't even read it carefully. Wonder where it went?!

Comment: @PG1995 Yes, I saw and read this other answer as well. It must have been removed by the author.

Comment: Could you put units on the graphs? It was my answer that I have deleted since it was incorrect in the sense that I did not think the perturbations could reverse in sign, even instantaneously.

Comment: @Thomas **Q1:** In the following image which has been taken from your linked webpage, they are showing, for Neptune, a smooth sine wave with period of 165 years (orbital period of Neptune). I think in reality, there will be small oscillations superimposed on that smooth curve. Mercury completes its revolution in 88 days compared to 165 years revolution of Neptune and hence there will come a short period of time  when Mercury is in such a position in its orbit that Neptune starts giving it precession in opposite direction which doesn't last for long. For example, in the image at point A, Cont'd

Comment: Mercury is pulled in positive direction though the shown curve is going in negative direction. At point B, Mercury is pulled in negative direction while dominant portion of precession is headed toward positive direction. Do I make sense?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgZ0a.png

**Q2** If Mercury's orbital speed becomes too low while keeping the orbital speed of influencing planet the same, I think the magnitude of precession would increase. But if the Mercury's speed is increased, the magnitude of precession would decrease. Do I have it right?

Comment: @ProfRob I added units to the graphs. As for the sign change of the effect:  the precession angle changes sign when the disturbing potential force changes sign. If the disturbing outer planet is in opposition  the resultant force pulls Mercury outward (away from the sun), but in conjunction it pulls Mercury towards the Sun. In the latter case, the distance is greater though, so the force is smaller. So the net effect will still be an increasing precession angle (consistent with the fact that on average the planet position is a ring which will result in an average net outward force)

Comment: @PG1995 **Q1**: The curves are strictly speaking not continuous. They consist of points showing the location of the perihelion angle. Each point contains the integrated effect of a whole Mercury orbit, so by definition the orbit wobble of Mercury is averaged out here already

Comment: @PG1995 **Q2**: No, it is the other way around. The precession is faster for planets closer to the sun i.e. planets that are faster (see also the link to that website I gave in my answer, where the effect of changing planet velocity is shown)

Comment: @Thomas So, what I was saying in case of Q1 was correct? Regarding Q2, but in the linked webpage they only change the speed of influencing planet which is Venus. They didn't change speed for Mercury. I still think that if Venus speed is kept constant and Mercury's orbital speed is lowered, the precession would increase. If Mercury's speed is increased, the precession will decrease. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @PG1995 You would be correct with regard to Q1 if you would track Mercury's orbit continuously. As it is, only the position at perihelion is tracked, so that averages over the wobb;le of Mercury's orbit and you won't see it in this plot. You only see the wobble due to the disturbing planets, even if you zoom in closely As for Q2, you are right, the webpage is referring to the disturbing planet, but the precessing orbit definitely precesses faster for closer orbits (i,.e. higher velocities) as well, evem much more so than for the disturbing planet.

Comment: @PG1995 Just think about it:    the precession rate is measured per time interval. If the velocity of the planet in its orbit is small enough, it could only make a couple of orbits in 100 years. The precession for this would be even too small to measure. In any case, the velocity in a given orbit is fixed by Kepler laws. You can not just change it.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks you! *"If the velocity of the planet in its orbit is small enough, it could only make a couple of orbits in 100 years."* Yes, less orbital speed means less number of orbits in 100 years. But lesser speed also means that the the planet would be spending more time under the influence of influencing planet. In other words, influencing planet could impose its pull to precess the planet in a dominant direction for longer period for each full orbit. Honestly, now I think that increasing orbital speed or making it less would not affect the precession.

Comment: @PG1995 The only way to have a smaller velocity in the orbit would be to reduced the mass (i.e. the gravitational attraction) of the Sun. In this case, yes, the precession per orbit would be larger (it is actually proportional to the ratio of the mass of the disturbing planet to that of the Sun). The orbital period would go up though with the inverse square root of the Sun (Kepler's third law), so in a given time interval the precession would be proportional to the inverse square root of the Sun's mass. The velocity in turn would be proportional to the square root of the Sun's mass.